# Integral Residue Calculation

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Integral: $I =\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2(x^2+a^2)}\mathrm dx$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a > 0$.

Method 1:

We observe that there is a removable singularity at $x=0$. Thus a semicircle contour in the upper plane centered at $z=0$ and with a sufficiently large radius $R$ is used to calculate the integral.

We express $cosx$ as Re $e^{iz}$. A simple calculation of the residue shows that $I = \frac{\pi  (1-e^{-a})}{a^3}$.

Method 2:

The same as Method 1, instead we directly evaluate the residue without expressing $cosx$ as Re $e^{iz}$. It follows that $I = \frac{\pi (1-\cosh a)}{a^3}$.

Method 3:

Express $cosx$ as Re $e^{iz}$ in the first place. Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z^2(z^2+a^2)}$, then $I = $Re$ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(z)\mathrm dz $. Observe that there is a simple pole at $z = 0$. Use the following contour $C$ where $R$ sufficiently large and $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.[image]

Residue calculation shows that $J = \int_C f(z)\mathrm dz = \frac{\pi(1-e^{-a})}{a^3}$. $I = J - \int_{C_{\epsilon}} f(z)\mathrm dz$, the latter one equals $\frac{\pi}{a^2}$ via another residue argument. Then $I = \frac{\pi (1-e^{-a})}{a^3}-\frac{\pi}{a^2}$.

**Question:**

The results of 3 different approaches are different. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bcosx-1%2CPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Ba%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-%E2%88%9E%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) tells me that Method 3 yields the correct result, but I have no idea why the other two methods are incorrect. Please help point out the mistakes I made in Method 1 and Method 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1: When you write $\cos z=\Re(e^{iz})$ and taking the real part outside the integral you accidentally reintroduce a pole at $z=0$ coming from (seen on real axis as imaginary) $\simeq\frac{iz}{z^2(z^2+a^2)}\simeq\frac{i}{a^2z}$.  Integrating straight across the simple pole introduce half the residue into the calculation as you can see.

Method 2: $\lvert\cos(R e^{i\theta})-1\rvert\simeq \cosh R$ blows up on a large part of the upper semicircle contour.

Method 3 is the only correct one.

Comment: Thank you! I have seen that Jordan's Lemma only assures that for **positive only** real number $k$, as $f(z)$ vanishes as $R$ approaches infinity, integrating $e^{ikz}f(z)$ alongside the upper semicircle yields $0$. If I evaluate the cosine part directly, it leaves a $e^{-iz}$ part in the exponential expansion and thus does not satisfy the requirement of Jordan's Lemma.